# How can i get rid of many vertices?

Tags: vertices

How can i get rid of so many points? I applied bevel modifier to round the edges of a plane.

[image]

Comment: Select all and Delete (X) > Disolve Limited ?

Comment: or Alt M > Merge By Distance?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all your vertices, go in the header menu > *Select > Checker Deselect*:

[image]

Then you can change the options in the *Operator* box, and delete with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*:

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/3zGgvAE

Comment: doesen t work i tried

Comment: what's happening exactly? I can't see any reason why it would not work, please retry

Comment: Nothing happen when i select these and i prex x and disolve vertices

Comment: so Checker Deselect works?

Comment: yes i can select with it but i can t delete

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/